# $C$ is a $3\times5$ matrix and $\{s,t,u,v,w\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors in $\Bbb R^5$. $Cu=0,Cv=0$, and $Cw=0$. Answer the following

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

**What are the possible values of the nullity of $C$?**
I said the nullity must be at least $3$, and the rank must be at most $2$ because the null space has at least a dimension of $3$.

**What are the possible values for the rank of $C$?**
See above.

**Is $Cx = b$ consistent for every choice of $b$ in $\Bbb R^3$?**
I want to say no because I'm not given any vectors in $C$ so I can't conclude whether or not it is consistent.

**Suppose in addition that $\{Cs,Ct\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors. What would your answer to the first and second questions be now?**

Nullity must be $5$, therefore the rank must be $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you missed a few points.

(1) Note that the question is after *all* the *possible* values of $C$'s nullity, at least 3 is a bit inconcrete. For example the nullity cannot be 7 (as $C \in \def\M{\operatorname{Mat}}\M_{3,5}(\def\R{\mathbf R}\R)$, and hence $\def\nul{\operatorname{nullity}}0 \le \nul C \le 5$, together with your remark we have that 
$$ \nul C \in \{3,4,5\} $$

(2) Here you are correct, we must have $\def\r{\operatorname{rank}}\r C \in \{0,1,2\}$.

(3) Here you missed the track, note that we do not have that $Cs = Ct = 0$, but that $\{Cs, Ct\}$ is linear *independent*. Hence, the image of $C$ is at least two-dimensional (as it contains $Cs$ and $Ct$). This gives $\r C \ge 2$ and (1) and (2) imply $$ \nul C =3, \r C = 2$$

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about the maximum nullity. Thanks for reminding me! Also, what do you mean by "image"? I've never heard my professor use that word when describing matrices.

Comment: Could I say that there must be at least 2 vectors in C that do not contain free variables?

Comment: The image is the subset of $\mathbf R^3$, which consists of the vectors $\{Cx: x \in \mathbf R^5\}$, it is spanned by $C$'s columns, its also called "column space".

Comment: Ah ok, and since the rank is equal to the dimension of the column space, it must be at least 2. On a side note, because the rank is two or less in the first part of the problem (which is less than the dimension of R^3), does that mean it is impossible to have consistent solutions in Cx=b? Sorry for all of the questions

Comment: If the rank is two, say, than $Cx = b$ will either have an infinite number of solutions (in case, $b$ lies in the column space) or be unsolvable (otherwise)